# Is there a built in function to convert a NodeList to a real list (ghcjs-dom)?

Tags: haskell, dom, ghcjs, ghcjs-dom

How can I convert the result of `Element.querySelectorAll body "h1"` which is `IO NodeList` to `IO (List Node)`. I know I could write a function myself. Is there a builtin function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My implementation:

```
nodeListToList nl = nl
       & NodeList.getLength
     <&> (\x -> [0..x - 1])
     >>= mapM (item nl)
     <&> catMaybes
```